# Auto retrieve Data from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 pages in PHP ( insert.php , retrieve.php )

insert.php , has the following:

1)Form  2)inputbox  3)submit button(insert)  4)div (div id='data').

retrieve.php :

has code to retrive/select rows from MySQL database(table) :
MySQL."Select * from table"........
while(...) { .. }

I need ajax code/jQuery , whatever to keep retrieving(getting) results from retrive.php and put them into div id='data' without page refresh . 
maybe this has to set a timer=1sec .

Comment: And your question is now... what?

Comment: its obvious what he is asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need:

- Write PHP script that and make sure it work (without JavaScript)
- Test it
- If success, then you need to start adopting this one to "jquery-ajax"

For example,

Your php script might look similar to this one:

```
<?php

//suppose we already connected 

$query = "SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE ...";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Just Ensure that it's not FALSE 
if ( !$result ){
  die('wrong query');
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  print $row['column']; /// and so on..
}
```

Ok, suppose you already know that it does work.

Now you'd implement timer to retrieve that after 1 sec (==1000m)
And you have to change the content of the div accordingly.

```
<script>

  $(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){

     $.post('path_to_your_scr_php.php', { /* Data in JSON format, if needed, use it like: key: val */ }, function(respond){

        $("#id_of_the_div_you_want_to_change").html(respond);
     })

   }, 1000);
  });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout(function, millisDelay)`

```
  setTimeout(function()
    {

        $("form").submit(function() {
            jQuery.post({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "retreive.php",
              data: FORM_PARAMETERS_HERE
          });
          return true;
        });
    }, 1000); //1000 milisec = 1 sec
```

Comment: hey PoeHah , thank you very much, could you please tell the difference between setTimeout & setInterval ? aren't they alike ? thank you.